# Combining 2 forms in symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an entity Book which contains:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Reviewr\ReviewsBundle\Entity\Review", mappedBy="bookID")
 */
protected $reviews;
```

Within the Review entity i have fields to represent:

```
userID
bookID
posted
comment
```

Within my BookType, I am trying to create the form which also includes the fields from the ReviewType form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('author')
        ->add('title')
        ->add('summary')
        ->add('reviews', ReviewType::class)
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
}
```

However, i can't seem to get this working. im just trying to have a form which uses fields from the book entity and review entity in one.

I recieve this error:

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Reviewr\ReviewsBundle\Entity\Review, but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
With the current answer, it finally displays something.. just a string "Reviews" rather than the fields from the ReviewType form (userID, bookID, posted and comment) as shown in the image below:

[image]

Why is it not displaying the fields?

Comment: Did you tried to use EntityType in your ReviewType?

Comment: @DanCostinel I've updated the question so you understand what is happening better

Comment: I guess that "Reviews" string is displayed by your `{{ form_end(form) }}`. See if you've rendered the respective field properly.

Comment: @DanCostinel Nope I just use form_end(form).. how should I render it because form_widget(form.reviews.userID) doesn't work either

Comment: Make a `{{ dump(form) }}` and see what descendants you get for that field.

Comment: @DanCostinel Okay, so I have all the expected fields from BookType.. i have the reviews field which is an array but doesn't contain any children

Comment: This means the solution given by @Dmitry is not the right one. See [this](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-relations) for more info on how to set a ManyToOne relationship, and its inverse side.

Comment: @DanCostinel Are you saying i need a different relation?

Comment: @DanCostinel I followed the link, but it hasn't helped?

Comment: No, you don't need a new relation. The `@OneToMany` in Book entity, and `@ManyToOne` in Review entity is enough. But are some intermediary steps you need to follow, in order to make things work. And the tutorial I've linked, explains those steps quite well. I suggest you read it carefully.

Comment: @DanCostinel I dont think what i am trying to achieve is possible, i have tried so many things

Answer (score 0):

Since your book has many reviews (not one), you must map review as a collection type, each entry of which would be of type Review

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('author')
        ->add('title')
        ->add('summary')
        ->add('reviews', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ReviewType::class
        ))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
}
```

See more details in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: When I do this, it just displays the string "Reviews" within the form, rather than all of its fields (userID, posted, bookID and comment)

Comment: This is normal behavior. You need to make an "add" button that the user of your form can press to add a new review. Only if you EDIT an existing book which have reviews already you will see the reviews. I think that you have to work this course out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to display reviews for a particular book, you need to implement a `OneToMany` relation in `Book` entity (as the inverse side), and a `ManyToOne` relation in `Review` entity (as the owning side).

I've searched for complete examples, and I couldn't find any, so here's my try:

1) Create the `Book` and `Review` entities, without any relationship, and create them in the database too. You'll get an error if you try to create the tables alongside the relationships, if the tables are not already being present in the database.

2) Now you can create the relationships

```
# AppBundle\Entity\Book.php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
...
class Book
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="book")
 */
private $reviews;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->reviews = new ArrayCollection();
}
//... getters and setters for extra fields you might have
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection|Review[]
 */
public function getReviews()
{
    return $this->reviews;
}
// Notice here you don't need the setReviews() setter!



# AppBundle/Entity/Review.php
use AppBundle\Entity\Book;
...
class Review
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="reviews")
 */
private $book;
//... getters and setters for extra fields you might have
/**
 * @return Review
 */
public function getBook()
{
    return $this->book;
}

/**
 * Notice here is passed the entire book object
 * @param Book $book
 * @return $this
 */
public function setBook(Book $book)
{
    $this->book = $book;
    return $this;
}
```

3) Apply these relations by creating the migrations or by using `doctrine:schema:update --force` command.

4) Create the forms, based on the entities

-> BookType: `php bin/console doctrine:generate:form AppBundle:Book`

-> ReviewType: `php bin/console doctrine:generate:form AppBundle:Review`, and you need to use the `EntityType` in order to get the book belonging to that array of reviews.

```
# AppBundle/Form/ReviewType.php
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
...
class ReviewType extends AbstractType
...
->add('book', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Book',
    'placeholder' => ' ',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('b');
    },
    'choice_label' => function($book){
        return $book->getId();// in the <select> options put the ids from Book entity
    },
    'multiple' => false, // a user can select only one option per submission
    'expanded' => false // options will be presented in a <select> dropdown; set this to true, to present the data in checkboxes
])
```

5) Action for creating and saving a book, in the controller:

```
# AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
use AppBundle\Entity\Book;
use AppBundle\Form\BookType;
...
/**
 * @Route("/book", name="book")
 */
public function bookAction(Request $request)
{
    $book = new Book();
    $form = $this->createForm(BookType::class, $book, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('book'),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($book);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('book');
    }
    return $this->render('default/book.html.twig', ['form'=>$form->createView()]);
}
```

6) Action for creating and saving a review, in the controller

```
# AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
use AppBundle\Entity\Review;
use AppBundle\Form\ReviewType;
...
/**
 * @Route("/review", name="review")
 */
public function reviewAction(Request $request)
{
    $review = new Review();
    $form = $this->createForm(ReviewType::class, $review, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('review'),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($review);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('review');
    }
    return $this->render('default/review.html.twig', ['form'=>$form->createView()]);
}
```

7) For displaying the reviews for a particular book:

```
# AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $reviews = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Review')->findAll();

    if (!$reviews) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No review(s) found!');
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig',['reviews'=>$reviews]);
}
```

8) The view to display the reviews (for book and review, just print the forms, so I won't post the code, as is trivial)

```
# app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% for review in reviews %}
        {{ review.comment ~ '-' ~ review.book.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```