# Symfony Forms combination for ManyToOne relation

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have field `customers` - drop down exist customer. And have customer, like CollectionType, `'entry_type' => CustomerForm::class,` but I using example for ManyToMany relation but my relation ManyToOne and I need change logic for my form, needed create only one costomer in `CustomerForm::class` 
  I read cook book [form_collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) And when I added new customer form, like `CollectionType::class`, when submit form have error

`Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Customer", "array" given`

in request

```
economy_bundle_outbound_invoice = {array} [4]
companyReference = "wwwww"
customerReference = "wwww"
customer = {array} [2]
 0 = {array} [1]
  name = "wwww"
 1 = {array} [1]
  name = ""
submit = ""
```

And I understand this is example for ManyToMany. My question how to create form for new Invoice and button for add new customer if needed

Now my form(need add exists customer from DB with dropdown)

```
        $builder
        ->add('companyReference')
        ->add('customerReference')

        ->add('customer', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => CustomerForm::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
        ))

        ->add('customers', 'entity', array(
            'class' => Customer::class,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control select2 all_customers'),
            'property' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choice Customer',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                /** @var CustomerRepository  $repository */
                return $repository->getAllQuery();
            },
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            )
        );
```

CustomerForm

```
    class CustomerForm extends AbstractType
   {
        $builder
        ->add('name');
```

My template

```
{% extends "ERP/economy/economy.html.twig" %}
{% trans_default_domain "invoicing" %}

{% set active_tab = "inbound_invoices" %}
{% block title %}HouseOptima ERP - Outbound Invoices{% endblock %}


{% block tab_content %}


{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.companyReference) }}
{{ form_row(form.customerReference) }}
{{ form_row(form.customers) }}

<h3>Customer</h3>
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.customer.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% for customer in form.customer %}
        <li>{{ form_row(customer.name) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{{ form_end(form) }}
<script>

    var $collectionHolder;
    var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_customer_link">Add a customer</a>');
    var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');
        $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
        $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

       $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });
    });



    $('.all_customers').on('change', function () {
        var dd = $('#economy_bundle_outbound_invoice_customers option:selected').val();

        console.log(dd);
        if (dd == '') {
            $('ul.tags').find('li').show();
        } else {
            $('ul.tags').find('li').hide();
        }
    });

    function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
        var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
        var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
        var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
        $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
        var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
        $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
    }
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to use an `EntityType` instead of `CollectionType`. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41387981/4548751) an example.

Comment: I need create new Customer, not selected exist in dropdown. Update my question

Comment: I have field `customers` - drop down exist customer. And have customer, like CollectionType, `'entry_type' => CustomerForm::class,` but I using example for ManyToMany relation but my relation ManyToOne and I need change logic for my form, needed create only one costomer in `CustomerForm::class`